# Is it possible to change the number format category of individual Y-axis scales in Spotfire using IronPython script?

Tags: ironpython, spotfire

I am new to spotfire and I am trying to apply different Y axes scales and format each one according to a document property that is changeable with a dropdown.

Here is the code I am using, this script launches every time we change the dropdown value:

```
import System
from Spotfire.Dxp.Data import *
from Spotfire.Dxp.Application.Visuals import *
from Spotfire.Dxp.Data.Formatters import *

viz = v.As[CombinationChart]()
viz.YAxis.IndividualScaling = True
formatterRight = DataType.Real.CreateFormatter()
formatterLeft = DataType.Real.CreateFormatter()
currentFormatting=viz.YAxis.Scale.Formatting
currentFormatting.Clear()
metric = Document.Properties["MetricProperty"]
if metric == "A":  
        viz.YAxis.Expression = 'Sum([A]) As [Total], Sum([A]) THEN [Value] / Sum([Value]) OVER      (All([Axis.Color])) As [Percentage]'
        formatterLeft.Category = NumberFormatCategory.Currency
        formatterRight.Category = NumberFormatCategory.Percentage
else:
        viz.YAxis.Expression ='Avg([A percent]) As [Total], Avg([A percent]) THEN [Value] / Sum([Value]) OVER (All([Axis.Color])) As [Percentage]'
        formatterLeft.Category = NumberFormatCategory.Percentage
        formatterRight.Category = NumberFormatCategory.Percentage
viz.YAxis.Scale.Formatting.IndexedRealFormatter["Percentage"] = formatterRight 
viz.YAxis.Scale.Formatting.IndexedRealFormatter["Total"] = formatterLeft
```

Unfortunately this script doesn't do the required job (assign the correct number format category to each scale), in fact only the Y axis changes expression but the formatting doesn't change and when set manually is always getting back to default (meaning that the clear method is working fine)
I think accessing each scale formatter with `IndexedRealFormatter` isn't working.

I am using Spotfire 11.4 and IronPython 2.7

Comment: without having looked at in in depth, could it be possible that the two formatterLeft/Right statements for Percentage should be indented as in the rest of the if/else block?

Comment: they are correctly indented in the code i fixed it here too

Answer (score 0):

Without seeing your exact setup, I can't really say what is going wrong.

I took the code from your StackOverflow question and created some dummy data. I made a 3 column table `X`, `A`, `A Percent`. `X` and `A Percent` were random percentages, and `A` was a random number between 0 and 1000.

When I ran the script, I got an error about `CreateFormatter` being depreciated and to use `CreateLocalizedFormatter` instead. When I changed that and ran the code, it worked for me. So maybe try that and see?

Comment: Hi, I tried `CreateLocalizedFormatter` and it didn't work still, the code works if I am only applying it to Y axis, but when it comes to applying a formatter to only a scale of many in the Y axis the code doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me (ignore the exact expression, just an example). I added the docking so that when you have multiple y axis one scale is assigned to the left and one to the right. I had to play around with aliases and parentheses though to make it work.

```
from Spotfire.Dxp.Data import *
from Spotfire.Dxp.Application.Visuals import *
from Spotfire.Dxp.Data.Formatters import *

viz = v.As[CombinationChart]()
viz.YAxis.IndividualScaling = True
formatterRight = DataType.Real.CreateLocalizedFormatter()
formatterLeft = DataType.Real.CreateLocalizedFormatter()
currentFormatting=viz.YAxis.Scale.Formatting
currentFormatting.Clear()
metric = Document.Properties["MetricProperty"]
if metric == "A":  
    viz.YAxis.Expression = 'Sum([Sepal_Length]) as Total, Sum([Petal_Length]) as Percentage'
    viz.YAxis.Scale.IndexedDock["Total"] = ScaleDock.Near;
    viz.YAxis.Scale.IndexedDock["Percentage"] = ScaleDock.Far;
    formatterLeft.Category = NumberFormatCategory.Currency
    formatterRight.Category = NumberFormatCategory.Percentage
else:
    viz.YAxis.Expression ='Sum([Sepal_Length])/2 as Total, Sum([Petal_Length])/2 as Percentage'
    viz.YAxis.Scale.IndexedDock["Total"] = ScaleDock.Near;
    viz.YAxis.Scale.IndexedDock["Percentage"] = ScaleDock.Far;
    formatterLeft.Category = NumberFormatCategory.Percentage
    formatterRight.Category = NumberFormatCategory.Percentage
viz.YAxis.Scale.Formatting.IndexedRealFormatter["Percentage"] = formatterRight 
viz.YAxis.Scale.Formatting.IndexedRealFormatter["Total"] = formatterLeft
```